# Regex number string number string loop

Tags: regex

My string is:

```
$str='Move 10 Casio Watch 20 Apple Iphone 100 Apple Macbook to store';
```

I have used:

```
preg_match_all('| ([0-9]+) (.*) |', $str, $matches);
```

But it only matches the first letter of the product name.

My result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  10 Casio 
            [1] =>  20 Apple 
            [2] =>  100 Apple 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => 20
            [2] => 100
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Casio
            [1] => Apple
            [2] => Apple
        )
)
```

Comment: What is **exactly** the output you are expecting?

Comment: I want get

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  10 Casio Watch
            [1] =>  20 Apple Iphone
            [2] =>  100 Apple Macbook
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => 20
            [2] => 100
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Casio Watch
            [1] => Apple Iphone
            [2] => Apple Macbook
        )
)

Comment: And does the product name always consist of two words, following a number?  Can you give us some rules here?

Comment: My product any words (1->10 words) My rules is number name number name number name ........... My regex only get first of product name. I Want get full name of product

Comment: Try this [`\d+ \K(?: ?[A-Z][a-z]+)+`](https://regex101.com/r/iLYiMX/1)

Comment: Thanks, \d+ \K(?: ?[A-Z][a-z]+)+ is true, but it false while product name is unicode. Ex Quả Táo

Comment: Use unicode flag `u`.

Comment: Thankyou verymuch Srdjan M.  :)

Answer (score 1):

**Regex**: [`\d+ \K(?: ?[A-Z][a-z]+)+`](https://regex101.com/r/iLYiMX/1)

**Details**:

- `\d+` matches a digit between one and unlimited times
- `\K` resets the starting point of the reported match
- `(?:)` non-capturing group
- `?` Match space char between zero and one times
- `[A-Z]` match upper case char
- `[a-z]+` match lower case char between one and unlimited times
- `(?:)+` repeat matching between one and unlimited times

**PHP code**:

```
$str = 'Move 10 Casio Watch 20 Apple Iphone 100 Apple Macbook to store';
preg_match_all("~\d+ \K(?: ?[A-Z][a-z]+)+~", $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Casio Watch
    [1] => Apple Iphone
    [2] => Apple Macbook
)
```

Comment: $str = 'Move 10 Casio Watch 20 Apple Iphone8 100 Apple Macbook';

I want get 
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Casio Watch
            [1] => 10
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Apple Iphone8
            [1] => 20
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Apple Macbook
            [1] => 100
        )

)

Please help me