# Regex to get number in string

Tags: php, regex

My string is

```
$str='You have 1 iphone5 10 iphone6 50 iphone7 in bag';
```

I want regex to preg_match have result below

Array
(

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => iphone5
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 10
        [1] => iphone6
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 50
        [1] => iphone7
    )
```

)

Please help me

Comment: Still trying to figure out the solution for your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52088575/regex-number-string-number-string-loop)?

Comment: What regex or search attempts did you try so far? ("Please help me" does not generally indicate effort.)

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/y6qOas/1/

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach using `preg_match_all`:

```
$str='You have 1 iphone5 10 iphone6 50 iphone7 in bag';
preg_match_all("/(\d+)\s+(\S+)/", $str, $matches);
$output = array();
for ($i = 0, $l = count($matches[1]); $i < $l; ++$i) {
    $output[$i] = array($matches[1][$i], $matches[2][$i]);
}
print_r($output);

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => iphone5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => iphone6
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 50
            [1] => iphone7
        )

)
```

The idea is to first capture all quantities and phone models using `preg_match_all`.  Then, we iterate those results and generate the output array of arrays which you expect.

Comment: Thanks. But if my string is   $str='You have 1 apple iphone5 10 apple iphone6 50 apple iphone7 in bag'; your code not run

Comment: @ÁnhTrăng Now you are changing your question.  And it's not nice to do that once other people have already answered.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$str='You have 1 iphone5 10 iphone6 50 iphone7 in bag';

preg_match_all("/(\d+)\s+(\w+)/", $str, $matches);

$result = [];

foreach($matches[0] as $key=>$value) {
  $result[] = array($matches[1][$key],$matches[2][$key]);
}

var_dump($result);
```